# Why both `make clean` and `make mrproper` are used?

Tags: linux, make, gnu

It is written in the linux kernel `Makefile` that

```
clean - Remove most generated files but keep the config and
        enough build support to build external modules
mrproper - Remove all generated files + config + various backup files
```

And it is stated on the [arch docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Traditional_compilation) that

> To finalise the preparation, ensure that the kernel tree is absolutely clean;
>
> `$ make clean && make mrproper`

So if `make mrproper` does a more thorough remove, why is the `make clean` used?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Cleaning is done on three levels, as described in a comment in the [Linux kernel Makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile):

```
###
# Cleaning is done on three levels.
# make clean     Delete most generated files
#                Leave enough to build external modules
# make mrproper  Delete the current configuration, and all generated files
# make distclean Remove editor backup files, patch leftover files and the like
```

According to the Makefile, the `mrproper` target depends on the `clean` target (see [line 1421](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile#L1421)). Additionally, the `distclean` target depends on `mrproper`.

Executing `make mrproper` will therefore be enough as it would also remove the same things as what the `clean` target would do (and more).

The `mrproper` target was added in 1993 (Linux 0.97.7) and has always depended on the `clean` target.  This means that it was never necessary to use *both* targets as in `make clean && make mrproper`.

Historic reference: https://archive.org/details/git-history-of-linux

Comment: @derobert wow, great. So `make clean` is redundant, right?

Comment: @sitilge yes, it's redundant, as make will run it anyway when you run `make mrproper`.

Answer (score 3):

`clean` is a prerequisite for `mrproper` target in [Makefile](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12.8/source/Makefile#L1324), so executing `make clean` separately is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular instruction (`make clean && make mrproper`) yes, it's pointless (it's like saying remove all squares, then remove all squares and all triangles)...but `make clean` is normally much more useful than `make mrproper` (because the last thing you want, with the vast majority of kernel builds, is to trash your `.config`)... so perhaps someone wrote the instruction that way purely as a helpful reminder of the difference (i.e. to remind you that the second part was going to trash your `.config`, so back it up now, if you're used to running `make clean` and then being able to build as usual).